# How to download app data in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am able to download my app data in organizer window in Xcode 5 , but when I tried to do the same in Xcode 6 , I couldn't see the option download of app data in organizer window. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the organizer window, with the device selected, select the application whose data you want to download then click the gear icon and select Download Container.

[image]

Comment: You went in a minute earlier :)

Comment: when I download the container, I can see the files but when I try to open an image its not working

Answer (score 2):

Following Are the steps to download App data from XCode 6

1.Go to **Organizer >> Device >> Select your device** .

2. Now **select the app** for which you want to download app data
3. At bottom there are three buttons click Settings iCon and select **Download Container**