# IOS app 'The application could not be verified' on IPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode4

The app which i created worked well in all devices other than IPhone6 . I got the following error message in XCODE 'The application could not be verified.' . I deleted the app and then reinstalled it as per the suggestion given in the link:

[iOS app 'The application could not be verified' only on one device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231338/ios-app-the-application-could-not-be-verified-only-on-one-device)

I want to know that what might be the actual cause of this error message. !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS app 'The application could not be verified' only on one device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231338/ios-app-the-application-could-not-be-verified-only-on-one-device)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think, this is an xCode issue. This can happen under many conditions. Like-

- Provisioning Profile mismatch:

  *Scenario 1:*

  When first time, you had built or installed the app in your device, you may have used a different certificate(paired with a different provisioning profile) than now. So, when you try to re-run the app, the device got confused. The ways to fix it-

  1. Delete the existing app and re-build. That way, you don't have to figure out which certificate, you used the first time.
  2. However, if you know which certificate and provisioning profile you used earlier, then just switch to those.

  *Scenario 2:*

  May be you are trying to use distribution profile where you supposed to use development profile.Fix-

  Assign any valid development provisioning profile under the code signing.

[image]

- Device not added:

  1. May be the device is not added in your developer account under Devices or
  2. May be the device is added under Devices, but when you created the provisioning profile, you forgot to select the device on which you are trying to run your app.

Comment: No,the certificate is same. But i was running the app after a long time, thats all.

Comment: this worked well for me. I removed the existing build and re-installed it.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that your are using the latest version of XCode i.e 6 for creating the build, and then tell us what is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I am using the latest version. This error doesn't show up often. But whenever i'm getting this error , i have to delete the app from IPhone. Then only the app works properly.

Comment: deleting the app and trying again has been the only thing that has worked for me