# App Installation Failed Xcode Version 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I had a installation failure message when trying to build my application on Xcode 7.0

[image]

what does this message mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app 'The application could not be verified' only on one device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231338/ios-app-the-application-could-not-be-verified-only-on-one-device)

Answer (score 0):

Reset the simulator and Clean and build the code.

If you are trying to run app in device than check all cerficates are verified and uninstall app and try to run again.