# Debug core data application in production

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I developed an application with xcode for ios and it's now in production. I have some bugs I can not reproduce in dev but which happen in production.

How can I explore core data of production ipad and debug it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect the device via USB to your computer, you can [download the app data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937785/how-to-download-app-data-in-xcode-6), this will include the database file. If you can't, you have to rely on 3rd party solutions like [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) which can perform the same task. I believe this would only work for apps which are not downloaded via the App Store.

Another option would be to include a button in the app to send the database to a server. A lot of my enterprise apps include this functionality, because it makes issue reproducing a lot simpler. But you would need a new version of the app for this.